# Python - Using 2d map() functional programing

Tags: python, numpy, functional-programming, sympy

Im trying to map an array to a function. Then map that that array into another function but not sure how to deal with map type object or how to map multidimensional arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

nn = np.arange(2)
n= len(nn)
x0=0
y0=0
r=10
num=11

def func1(i):
    x1, y1 = x0 + r * sp.cos(2 * sp.pi * i / n), y0 + r * sp.sin(2 * sp.pi * i / n)
    return np.array([sp.N(x1),sp.N(y1)])

def func2(x1,y1):
    x, y = np.linspace(x0, x1, num), np.linspace(y0, y1, num)
    return x,y


map1=map(func1,nn)
map2=map(func2,map1[0],map1[1])
```

Want expect out put to be an array `[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],[[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]`

Comment: why `sympy`?  You haven't created any symbols

Comment: `map` is a python construct like a list comprehension or for loop.  Nothing special or fast.

Comment: `func1(nn)` is much more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd express this as a single loop, or list comprehension. The two functions are chained, not mapped

```
In [60]: def func1(i):
    ...:     x1, y1 = x0 + r * sp.cos(2 * sp.pi * i / n), y0 + r * sp.sin(2 * sp
    ...: .pi * i / n)
    ...:     print(x1,y1)
    ...:     return np.array([int(x1),int(y1)])
    ...: 
    ...: def func2(x1,y1):
    ...:     x, y = np.linspace(x0, x1, num), np.linspace(y0, y1, num)
    ...:     return x,y
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [61]: [func2(*func1(i)) for i in range(2)]
10 0
-10 0
Out[61]: 
[(array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.]),
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
 (array([  0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.,  -6.,  -7.,  -8.,  -9., -10.]),
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))]
In [62]: np.array(_, int)
Out[62]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,  -1,  -2,  -3,  -4,  -5,  -6,  -7,  -8,  -9, -10],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]]])
```

To use `map`:

```
np.array(list(map(lambda i: func2(*func1(i)), range(2))),int)
```

The use of `sympy` is bit obscure, but apparently it's to get "exact" sin/cos values - but they still have to be converted to `int` to be used by `numpy`.  Use of `sympy` together with `numpy` has lots of pitfalls.

Comment: yes i used it to get exact values. good to know thanks

Comment: is there a better way for sin(pi) to return zero in numpy?